# AS3 test for Class type

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a function which is giving me the class type of an object that I pass in.

```
public function getClass(obj:Object):Class {
return Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(obj)));
}
```

Now if I do this

```
trace(getClass(panelStack[0]));
```

I get [class InfoPanel] in the output window which is correct

But if I do this

```
trace(getClass(panelStack[0]) is InfoPanel);
```

I get false, but I'm expecting true.

Could anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong here. I'm just about to tear the last parts of my hair out!!!

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: `is` only works for instances

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there, just remove the `getClass()` call. Try this instead:

```
trace(panelStack[0] is InfoPanel);
```

The `is` operator can be used with any variable or expression to determine if it is a member of a particular data type. When you had made the call to `getClass()` you were essentially testing against completely different instance.

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense. Where were you 3 hours ago ;) Thanks so much for taking the time to post your solution.

Answer (score 6):

You should not use `is` but `==` ;)

Because `getClass(panelStack[0]) is Class`